# How to make the value not null in skewness in the extraction of the color moment feature?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction

I want to use the color moment feature extraction, which must get the value (`mean`, `standard deviation` and `skewness`) but the `skewness` value cannot be entered into the excel because there is a negative division value and the `skewness` result becomes (`Nan`), how can you still use it?

> <<RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
> hasil_akhir_skewS (skewnessS/totS)**(1/3)>>

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import xlsxwriter as xlsx

book = xlsx.Workbook('data_ayam.xlsx')
sheet = book.add_worksheet()
sheet.write(0, 0, 'file')

column = 1 
fitur = ['meanH','meanS','meanV', 'stdevH','stdevS','stdevV', 'skewnessH','skewnessS','skewnessV']
for i in fitur :
sheet.write(0, column, i)
column += 1

ayam_type = ['non_segar', 'segar']
sum_each_type = 100
row = 1
for i in ayam_type:
    for j in range(1, sum_each_type+1):
    column = 0 
    file_name = 'ayam/' + i + str(j) + '.jpg'
    print(file_name)
    sheet.write(row, column, file_name)
    column += 1

    #preprocessing
    img = cv2.imread(file_name, 1)
    resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))
    fitur = cv2.cvtColor(resized_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    H = fitur[:, :, 0]
    S = fitur[:, :, 1]
    V = fitur[:, :, 2]
    
    totH = H.size
    totS = S.size
    totV = V.size

    totalH = H.sum()
    totalS = S.sum()
    totalV = V.sum()

    #Mean
    meanH = totalH/totH #equivalent to file_name.mean()
    meanS= totalS/totS #equivalent to file_name.mean()
    meanV = totalV/totV #equivalent to file_name.mean()

    #Stdev
    vrH = ((H - meanH)**2).sum()
    vrS = ((S - meanS)**2).sum()
    vrV = ((V - meanV)**2).sum()
    hasil_akhir_stdH = math.sqrt((vrH/totH))
    hasil_akhir_stdS = math.sqrt((vrS/totS))
    hasil_akhir_stdV = math.sqrt((vrV/totV))
    
    #Skewness
    meanijH = (H - meanH)
    meanijS = (S - meanS)
    meanijV = (V - meanV)

    skewnessH = (meanijH**3).sum()
    skewnessS = (meanijS**3).sum()
    skewnessV = (meanijV**3).sum()

    hasil_akhir_skewH = (skewnessH/totH)**(1/3)
    hasil_akhir_skewS = (skewnessS/totS)**(1/3)
    hasil_akhir_skewV = (skewnessV/totV)**(1/3)
    hasil = [meanH, 
             meanS, 
             meanV, 
             hasil_akhir_stdH, 
             hasil_akhir_stdS, 
             hasil_akhir_stdV, 
             hasil_akhir_skewH, 
             hasil_akhir_skewS, 
             hasil_akhir_skewV]
    feature_props = {
        hasil[0],
        hasil[1],
        hasil[2],
        hasil[3],
        hasil[4],
        hasil[5],
        hasil[6],
        hasil[7],
        hasil[8]
    }
    for item in feature_props:
        sheet.write(row, column, item)
        column += 1
    row += 1  

book.close()
```

This is the error:

[image]

Comment: “Negative division value” doesn’t lead to NaN. It’s probably a 0/0.